# Releasing a vertex/index buffer causes warning

Tags: directx, directx-10

When releasing (Release()) a vertex buffer (ID3D10Buffer / D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER) which has been used for rendering in the previous frame I get a warning that the buffer is bound:

D3D10: INFO: ID3D10Device::IASetVertexBuffers: A currently bound VertexBuffer is being deleted; so naturally, will no longer be bound. [ STATE_SETTING INFO #31: IASETVERTEXBUFFERS_UNBINDDELETINGOBJECT ]

Is there a way I can unbind the buffer?

Thanks,

Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its anyway not a warning, but an info. It does not make ANY difference that you remove or not the buffer from being binded.

Answer (score 3):

Setup `NULL` buffers using `ID3D10Device::IASetVertexBuffers`. Or bind another buffer.